# SQL Server - auto-populate field in one table with value from another table in another Database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have two Azure SQL Server databases with the following as example:

```
Database Name: DataProp
Table Name: DataImports
Columns: SearchID, SourceID, Text, Status, Country

Database Name: Sources
Table Name: SourceInformation
Columns: SourceID, SourceTitle, Country
```

Right now, the `Country` column in the `DataProp` database is all NULL.  I need to auto-populate the `Country` field in `DataProp` with the values of the `Country` fields in the `Sources` database.  The common field between the two tables is `SourceID`.  I need to do this for all existing data, as well as have it occur for future records.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  A stored procedure that's set to run on a schedule?  If so, I would appreciate guidance on the T-SQL syntax.

*As a side-note, I looked at the possibility of a computed column, but this will not work for us b/c we maintain an Azure Search Index on our tables, and Azure Search can't index computed columns.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to directly write a join between tables in two different DBs. We had a similar problem and decided to move all tables into a single DB in separate schemas. I think in your case you can write a Webjob to pull in data from one table and update the second table. I also found one article related to this but haven't personally tried, so not sure if it works.

https://ppolyzos.com/2016/07/30/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-databases/

Comment: This is new ground for me (master keys and scoped credentials) but it looks very interesting and should prove helpful.  Thank you.